# Python - Twitter 1.14.3

Tags: python, twitter

I can't seem to find any [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter) on retrieving an authorised users favourite tweets from their list. Has anyone had any experience of doing this. So far I can authorise with the following code -

```
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError
import json

OAUTH_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
OAUTH_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxx'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

t = Twitter(auth=OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of retrieving favourite tweets, I have been successful in favouriting just unable to find a method, if it exists, allowing me to retrieve this data.

Comment: Try using twython instead. You might find it easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested it but there are some docs on the twitter api here

http://inventwithpython.com/twitter.html

Think it has the method/s you are after. Shouldn't be too hard to test it out now that you have the ground work done of authenticating etc.

Hope it helps

Keir